# what are three conditions that may be used with the join operation which specify how the join should merge data from two relations

Tags: sql, postgresql

What are three conditions that may be used with the join operation which specify how the join should merge
data from two relations?

I was expecting it would be Primary , Foreign Key & Constraints/ inner join and Outer join but those conditions are something different and I don't seem to find it.

Comment: `left`, `right` and `full` maybe for outer joins?

Comment: Please explain your specific question. There is no restriction on the column(s)/literal(s) that can be joined providing those column(s)/literal(s) types are compatible or can be cast to compatible types.